# call() a function within its own context

Tags: javascript, this

```js
var f = function() {
  this.x = 5;
  (function() {
    this.x = 3;
  })();
  console.log(this.x);
};

f.call(f);

f();

f.call();
```

Running `var f` as `f.call(f)` outputs `5`. When running it as `f()` or `f.call()` outputs `3`.

What happens in each case? What does the inner function's `this` refer to?

Comment: Don't confuse the two this references. Instead try to see there are two different stack frames. Each frame has a this reference. That this is either the default or it's been set by call(). The inner function can not be set. It's always the default. I think the default for this is window, but that depends if there is a module loader or not. I should know but I can't remember.

Comment: If you want to add some other scopes/context, use the `.bind(context)` method.

Comment: This is why you always should use strict mode…

Comment: It's also why you should use lambdas instead of anonymous functions

Answer (score 13, accepted):

#### First Case:

In the first you are calling the function. And inside the function the function itself i.e `f` is set as `this`. So in first example `this.x = 5;` sets the property `x` on the function.

When the inner function is called `this` refers to `window` object so `this.x = 3;` changes the `x` property of window object.

When it logs `console.log(this.x);` here the same property `x` which was set as property of function is logged.

#### Second Case:

In the second example `this` inside the outer function refers to `window` so when `this.x = 3;` is evaluated the `window.x` becomes `3`. As `this` refers to `window` in outer function so  `console.log(this.x);` logs `window.x` which is `3`

#### Conclusion:

The conclusion of the whole discussion is that if no argument is passed to `call()` then automatically `window` object is binded. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call#Parameters)

> **thisArg**
> Optional. The value of this provided for the call to a function. Note that this may not be the actual value seen by the method: if the method is a function in non-strict mode, **null and undefined will be replaced with the global object** and primitive values will be converted to objects.

See the below snippet.

```js
function foo(){
  console.log(this);
}
foo.call(foo); //foo function
foo.call(); //window object
```

Answer (score 5):

If there is no specific context, `this` will be `window`. Your inner function always runs without a context, so it'll set `window.x` to 3. If you call `f()`, it will also run with `this` being `window` therefore logging the 3.

If you however do `f.call(f)`, `this` will be the `f` function object, and it's `x` property will be set to 5.

```
  f.call(f)
  console.log(
    f.x, // 5
    window.x // 3
  );
```

I'd recommend stepping through it with the [debugger](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/) if it isn't clear yet.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `f` with a reference to itself, it sets the `x` property to 5 on the function and the inner anonymous function has its `this` referring to the window, so it sets window.x to 3. Outside the anonymous function, `this` still refers to the function `f`, so console.log(this.x) outputs 5.

When you invoke f using `f()` or `f.call()` the function f and the anonymous function inside it have a `this` reference set to the `window` (the default) and so changing the value of `this.x` inside or outside the anonymous function affects the output result.

You can see this clearly if you console.log the values of `this` inside the function f and inside the inner anonymous function.

```js
var f = function() {
 console.log("This inside function f:", this.toString());
  this.x = 5;
  (function() {
   console.log("This inside anonymous inner function:", this.toString());
    this.x = 3;
  })();
  console.log(this.x);
};
console.log("calling function x with this set to itself");
f.call(f);
console.log("---------------")
console.log("invoking function x with brackets ()")
f();
console.log("---------------")
console.log("calling function x without setting this context")
f.call();
console.log("---------------")
```

Answer (score 1):

Further to the other answers, should you want predictable behaviour, you have at least 2 methods available to you.

Method 1: (closure)

```
var f = function() {
  this.x = 5;
  var that = this;
  (function() {
    that.x = 3;
  })();
  console.log(this.x);
};

f.call(f); // 3

f(); // 3

f.call(); // 3
```

Method 2: (arrow function)

```
var f = () => {
  this.x = 5;
  (function() {
    this.x = 3;
  })();
  console.log(this.x);
};

f.call(f); // 3

f(); // 3

f.call(); // 3
```

Answer (score 0):

**'this' keyword refers to the context object in which the current code is executing.** Outside any function this refers to the global object.

By using `call()`, `apply()` functions the value of this can pass from one context to another context.

- So in the 1st case [**f.call(f)**] by calling the call function and
  giving the first argument as `f`, `this.x` refers to 5. So answer is
  printed as 5.
- 2nd case [**f()**] it is calling the function without using call
  function. So it refers the execution context of `this` as 3. So it
  prints as 3.
- In the third case [**f.call()**], inside the call function no
  argument is mentioned. So it refers to the global object and prints `3`
  as the output.